# Firebase how to order data inside child of a child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase database. I need to use OrderbyChild to sort data in my ionic app. Is it possible to sort all the categeroies OrderbyChild?

[image: firebase_data]

Comment: There is no way to sort such double-nested data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested